# Notificação de análise com símbolo vermelho

Tags: suporte, filas-de-análise

Ao ver as notificações de análise, reparei que ocasionalmente os alertas de análise surgem com o símbolo vermelho como imagem abaixo.
 Por que elas aparecem em vermelho?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque há muitas ações para serem analisadas, é só um indicador que precisa muito da sua ajuda, mais que as outras que estão em cinza.

Comment: Todo dia o de reabertura tá em vermelho.