# Como funciona a notificação de "muita coisa" nas filas de análise?

Tags: suporte, filas-de-análise

Nessa [pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8291/112052), onde questiona **por que aparece uma bolinha vermelha em certos itens da fila de análise**, foi respondido que elas aparecem quando tem muitos itens para serem analisados.

Mas a minha dúvida é: a partir de quantos itens passa a ser "muitos itens"?

- As filas de análise tem um prazo recomendado por item de análise?
- As filas de análise tem um máximo recomendado por fila?
- Se sim para uma das acimas, são números individuais por filas ou são para todas?